# signal SIGARBT error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

I get this error if I'll run my App in the iOS Simulator (iPhone 4-inch 32-bit iOS 7.1):

Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Error:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool 
   {
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
   }
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

**Console Report:**

```
   2014-04-26 14:09:24.039 Picxxr[2184:60b] -[ViewController filter1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x964d580
2014-04-26 14:09:24.041 Picxxr[2184:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController filter1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x964d580'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01d651e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01ae48e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01e02243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01d5550b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01d550ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01af6880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x007a63b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x007a6345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    8   UIKit                               0x008a7bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x008a7fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    10  UIKit                               0x008a7243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    11  UIKit                               0x00b3c2e3 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7166
    12  UIKit                               0x007e5a5a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    13  UIKit                               0x007e6971 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1021
    14  UIKit                               0x007b85f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    15  UIKit                               0x007a2353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01cee77f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01cee10b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01d0b1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01d0a9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01d0a7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x032155ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0321542b GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x007a4f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    24  Picxxr                              0x0000cd7d main + 141
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x03e0c701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Filter1 in a class called ViewController doesn't exist. You may have deleted an outlet or something from the code, but forgot to delete the link from the actual object in the storyboard. Right click on what was linked to Filter1 and see if it has the old (deleted) connection still.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you setup a button with an action of `filter1:` but you never added the `filter1:` method to your `ViewController` class.

Perhaps you defined the method as `filter1` instead of `filter1:`. The colon makes a huge difference.

If your method is really:

```
- (IBAction)filter1 {
}
```

Then you need to change the button to use the selector `filter1` instead of `filter1:`. Or change the method to:

```
- (IBAction)filter1:(id)sender {
}
```